# kotlin work with Resources (array and function parameter)

Tags: kotlin

I need to define array of RAW Resources by using kotlin for example

```
    var x = ArrayList<Resources > 
    x.add(R.raw.cat)
```

and the other question is to pass resource to function

```
fun myFun(res:Resources ){
   mp=MediaPlayer()
   mp.start(res)
 }
```

I will be very thanksfull for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You maybe need a `Int` instead of `Resources` to reference a resource id:

```
var x = ArrayList<Int> 
x.add(R.raw.cat)

fun myFun(resId: Int) {
    mp=MediaPlayer()
    mp.start(resId)
}
```